# Windows UI Library - how to invoke NavigationView.MenuItems added dynamically

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-template-studio

I'm using windows ui library and windows template studio. Currently, the `winui:NavigationView.MenuItems` are added in xaml.

```
    <winui:NavigationView>
        <winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" Icon="Home" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" />
        </winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Grid>
            <Frame x:Name="shellFrame" />
        </Grid>
    </winui:NavigationView>
```

And Now I add some more items in .cs code.

```
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            WinUI.NavigationViewItem navigationViewItem = new WinUI.NavigationViewItem();
            navigationViewItem.Content = "AAA " + i.ToString();
            navigationView.MenuItems.Add(navigationViewItem);
        }
```

How to write code, when I click the added item, app navigate to the related page.
A related repo is [here](https://github.com/hupo376787/InvokeNavigationViewItems.git).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration of windows template studio is applying an attached property(`helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo`) for per NavigationViewItem.

```
<winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" Icon="Document" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" />
```

So, if you want to create the NavigationViewItem in code-behind, you still need to apply the attached property for every NavigationViewItem like the following:

```
WinUI.NavigationViewItem navigationViewItem = new WinUI.NavigationViewItem();
navigationViewItem.Content = "AAA " + i.ToString();
navigationViewItem.SetValue(NavHelper.NavigateToProperty, typeof(Views.APage));
```